# How to determine the coordinates of the next rectangle on JPanel

Tags: java, graphics, rect, coordinate

i have an arraylist `RecArray` of objects with each object containing two int values, one for the width and for the height of a rectangle. Each rectangle's height and width are a multiple of ten. the rectangles have to be passed on to the surface  as in the given order in `RecArray` from left to right and from top to bottom. my problem is i can not find the x,y coordinates of the next rectangle. what im trying to do is, starting at the coordinate (0,0) i generate the first rectangle, add it to an arraylist `RecList`. Then i set the x and y coordinates. x becomes `x = x+RecArray.get(0).getLength1() + 1`. if x is greater than the width of the jpanel surface then it becomes 0 and y becomes `y = y + 10` . starting from the second object in the RecArray i try to generate rectangles with the given coordinates and width&height. Then i try to compare them with all the previous rectangles to see if there is any overlapping. if there is no overlapping, the rectangle will be drawn, if there is overlapping, the x coordinate of the rec becomes `x = RecList.get(j).width+1` and if that exceeds the width x becomes 0 and y is `y=y+10`. Then i regenate the current rectangle with the new coordinates and compare with the other rectangles in `RecList` again  till i find the right spot for the current rectangle.ive been dealing with that issue for the last 5 days and am really fed up now. i would greatly appreciate any tipps. and Please be patient with me. im still learning programming.

```
super.paintComponent(g);
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;     
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(x, y, RecArray.get(0).getWidth(),
              RecArray.get(0).getHeight());
RecList.add(rec);
recPaint(g2,RecArray.get(0)); 
x = x + RecArray.get(0).getWidth() + 1;
int i;
for (i = 1; i < RecArray.size(); i++) {
  if (x >= this.getArea().getWidth()) {
        x = 0;
        y = y + 10;
  }     
  Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle(x, y, RecArray.get(i)
              .getWidth(), RecArray.get(i).getheight());
  for (int j= 0; j < RecList.size(); j++) {
      if (!recIntersect(rec1, RecList.get(j))) {
         RecList.add(rec1);
         recPaint(g2,RecArray.get(i));
         break;
      } 
      else {
           x = RecList.get(j).width;
           if (x >= this.getFlaeche().getLength1()) {
               x = 0;
               y = y + 10;
           }
           rec1 = new Rectangle(x, y,RecArray.get(i).  .getWidth(),  
                 RecArray.get(i).getHeight());
      }
      x = x + RecArray.get(i).getWidth();
 } 
 //With this method using the given rec parameter a rectangle  will be drawn on the g2 and filled in blue colour
private void recPaint (Graphics2D g2, RecType rec){
      g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);  
      g2.fillRect(x, y, rec.getWidth(),
      rec.getLength2());
      g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      g2.drawRect(x, y, rec.getHeight(),
      rec.getLength2());
}
// returns true, if two rectangles overlap
private boolean recIntersect(Rectangle rec1, Rectangle rec2) {
   if( rec1.intersects(rec2)){
         return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Edit: apparently i haven't stated clearly what my problem is. my problem is, that the way i generate (x,y) coordinates of the rectangles is obviously wrong.  the way my algorithm works doesnt get the results i want. i want my rectangles to be placed neatly next to/above/below each other WITHOUT overlapping, which is not the case.

Comment: You have described in detail what your current algorithm does but I'm still note sure what exactly your problem is. Also please try to describe what you want to achieve in a figurative, understandable way (like "I want to fill my JPanel with my Rectangles without overlapping" or something, as I don't quite understand your goal).

Comment: Thx! im editing it right away.

Comment: Create a List of [Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html)s.  Calculate the X, Y coordinates **once**.  Draw the Rectangles as many times as needed.

Comment: Hi Gilbert, what do you mean by calculating the x,y coordinates once?could you pls elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Separate out your List of Rectangles.  Calculate the X, Y coordinates **once**.

Since I didn't have your object class, I used the Dimension class, which holds a width and a length.  I used the Rectangle class to hold the objects that will eventually be drawn in your Swing GUI.

Divide and conquer.  Separate out your GUI model, view, and controller(s).  This way, you can focus on one piece of the puzzle at a time.

Here are the results of my test code when I ran it with a drawing area of 500, 400.

```
java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=100,height=100]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=100,y=0,width=20,height=10]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=120,y=0,width=40,height=20]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=160,y=0,width=60,height=40]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=220,y=0,width=80,height=60]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=300,y=0,width=20,height=10]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=320,y=0,width=120,height=110]
```

Here are the results of my test code when I ran it with a drawing area of 200, 200.

```
java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=100,height=100]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=100,y=0,width=20,height=10]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=120,y=0,width=40,height=20]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=100,width=60,height=40]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=60,y=100,width=80,height=60]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=140,y=100,width=20,height=10]
```

And here's the code.  I fit rectangles on the X axis until I can't fit another rectangle.  Then I add the **maximum height** to Y, reset the X to zero, reset the maximum height and fit the next row of rectangles.

Create test applications like I did here and make sure that you can create the GUI model long before you create the GUI view and GUI controller.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CalculatingRectangles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CalculatingRectangles calculatingRectangles = new CalculatingRectangles();
        Dimension drawingArea = new Dimension(200, 200);

        List<Dimension> dimensions = new ArrayList<>();
        dimensions.add(new Dimension(100, 100));
        dimensions.add(new Dimension(20, 10));
        dimensions.add(new Dimension(40, 20));
        dimensions.add(new Dimension(60, 40));
        dimensions.add(new Dimension(80, 60));
        dimensions.add(new Dimension(20, 10));
        dimensions.add(new Dimension(120, 110));

        List<Rectangle> rectangles = calculatingRectangles
                .calculatingRectangles(drawingArea, dimensions);
        System.out.println(displayRectangles(rectangles));
    }

    private static String displayRectangles(List<Rectangle> rectangles) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Rectangle r : rectangles) {
            builder.append(r);
            builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

    public List<Rectangle> calculatingRectangles(Dimension drawingArea,
            List<Dimension> dimensions) {
        int width = drawingArea.width;
        int height = drawingArea.height;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int index = 0;
        int maxHeight = 0;

        boolean hasRoom = dimensions.size() > index;

        List<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<>();

        while (hasRoom) {
            Dimension d = dimensions.get(index);
            maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, d.height);

            if ((x + d.width) <= width && (y + maxHeight) <= height) {
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, d.width, d.height);
                x += d.width;
                rectangles.add(r);

                index++;
                if (index >= dimensions.size()) {
                    hasRoom = false;
                }

            } else {
                y += maxHeight;
                if (y > height) {
                    hasRoom = false;
                }
                x = 0;
            }

        }

        return rectangles;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Gilbert. Thx for your answer. but im still not sure if that gives me what i want. i guess i have a problem verbalising it. so here is a link showing a pic of what i want to get. http://www.naturstein-paradies.eu/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Verlegeplan_links_Travertin_roemischer_Verband.jpg   as you see the (x,p) positions can be completely random and not so regular as in your above examples. do you think your solution still applies to that?No gaps are allowed between the rectangles. thanks again for your huge answer!

Comment: The picture is not what you described in your question.  You're looking for a solution to the [Bin Packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).